# What are the documents necessary for a 15 year-old Nepalese to travel to India?

Tags: india, paperwork, nepali-citizens

I live in Nepal. I  will be 16 this December but I need to travel to India in September. I will get my citizenship only when I am 16. I neither have passport or voter card. I will be travelling alone. Can I travel? What are the documents required?

Comment: Jonathan, Your flag is invalid. Here a Nepalese citizen is travelling to India who does not have a passport issued by Nepal Govt.

Both are entirely different things, Your mark does not taste good!

Answer (score 1):

> Nepal and Bhutan nationals if entering India by land or air from the
>   Nepal or Bhutan border respectively do not require a passport for
>   entering into India. However, they are required to possess, authorized
>   identity proof. Further if they are entering India from a place other
>   than their own country then possession of passport is a must.

**No you do not require to have either a passport or a visa to enter India.
For more info read [here](http://www.indiamike.com/india/for-citizens-of-other-countries-visa-and-pio-oci-questions-f9/nepali-citizen-in-usa-travelling-to-india-t151071/)**

Hope it helps!